# How can i reverse dates on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to reverse this list so instead of it showing the first date I want the latest date to show up on top. So instead of the 19th I want the 21st on top.

**19 August 2015**

Creeme

Deja Tu Envidia

Debarata

**20 August 2015**

Ginza

Versace

**21 August 2015**

Cuando Le Doy ft. El Súper Nuevo

(The Controller)

```
def index
    @videos = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC")
    @topvideo = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC")


    @items = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at ", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
    @items_by_day = @items.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_day }
end
```

(The View)

```
<% @items_by_day.sort.each do |day, items| %>
<h1><%= day.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th></th>           
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <% for item in items %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.title %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<% @items_by_day.sort.each do |day, items| %>
```

With

```
<% @items_by_day.sort.reverse.each do |day, items| %>
```

Just like the `sort` method, there's a `reverse` method for arrays :)

Comment: finally it worked!!! i tried the reverse in all the wrong spots. I tried putting it in the controller not in the view.